# Which interface to choose for connecting my electric guitar to the computer?

Tags: guitar, computer

I am a beginner guitarist. I have an electric guitar and I recently downloaded the [Amplitube](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/amplitube/) software. Now I want to connect my guitar to my laptop computer. After some research, I discovered that there are two major ways to do this -

1. via the USB port (using a Guitar-to-USB Interface)
2. via the the mic-in port (using a 6.3mm (1/4") to 3.5mm (Mini) Headphone Adapter)

Please explain (in detail) which would be a better choice. Also please suggest a few good and affordable (I am not very rich) products available in the market for each category.

Comment: @slim No it is not a duplicate.

Comment: what about your question is not answered in the other one?

Comment: Closed as the other question gives you good advice on how to connect, and we don't do product recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the options you gave I suggest the first one.

To connect to the 3,5mm input is not a good option. There are several disadvantages & problems that might come up, the worst are latency, low sound quality and physical limitations with the 3,5 mm input. Latency means that when you play/record the audio interface might have a delay, late answer, in timing; which can be very annoying and frustrated when you are recording. It will make you play/record worst. The sound quality, sampling rate, conversion from analog to digital are also weak/poor quality and are also a downside that will make you disappointed.

I would go for a USB audio interface and avoid something too cheap. I suggest **[this](http://www.thomann.de/gb/m_audio_m_track.htm)** product/price range as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me. Could you please suggest me a few more guitar-to-usb converters (you may provide online stores' links, if you like). Also, what about this thing: Behringer UCG102 Guitar-to-USB Interface (http://www.amazon.com/Behringer-UCG102-Guitar-to-USB-Interface/dp/B000PAPO9W%3FSubscriptionId%3D14H876SFAKFS0EHBYQ02%26tag%3Dbookdablogonb-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB000PAPO9W)?

Comment: @Shravan, glad I could help. About your follow up question it's very much a question of price. Behringer is a big brand, they often make low price solutions that work for people who cannot spend too much money. So that is also an option for you.